# prevent change event on tab keydown

Tags: jquery

How to prevent `change` event when pressing tab key in an input?

I already have added `e.preventDefault()` to the `keydown` event handler

http://jsfiddle.net/949frs9j/1/

If you change the value of one input and press tab then the `change` event is triggered...

```
<input id="tab1" type="text"> <input id="tab2" type="text">

$('input').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 9){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(e.target.id == 'tab1'){
            $('#tab2').focus();
        }
        else{
            $('#tab1').focus();
        }
    }
}).change(function(){
    console.log('change');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prevent firing the `change` event from `keydown` event handler.
a workaround could be temporarily remove the `change` event handler when <kbd>Tab</kbd> button is pressed and re-bind it again after moving the focus to the next input. [Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/949frs9j/3/)

```
   $('#tab1').off('change', myChangeHandler);
   $('#tab2').focus();
   $('#tab1').on('change', myChangeHandler);
```

Another way is using a `flag` variable to help the `change` event handler distinguish `change` firing caused by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> from other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The change event is firing because the value of the element has changed... that's what it's for.

It would help if we knew why you were trying to stop the change event firing.